# Stratified random sampling in R

Tags: raster, r, sf, sampling, stratified-sampling

I want to generate 5 pairs of random points per each stratum. I have 4 strata that represent different rock types. For each rock type i want to generate 5 random points and to each random point I want to assign its respective pair at 10 meters distance (but it should still belong to the same stratum/category of rocks). So, altogether there should be 20 original random points and 20 additional (paired ones).

I have tried using `sampling::strata` (R package is called `sampling` and to get random points stratified per category the function `strata` is appropriate to use). See the code below. My sf object (data) is called `selected_rows` and the column with categories/strata is `Rock_name`. The size is 5 points per stratum.

```
units <- sampling::strata(
selected_rows, stratanames = "Rock_name", size = n_s[stratum], method = "srswr")

points = getdata(selected_rows, units) %>% st_as_sf()
```

My issue is now that I do not get coordinates of the random points rather the geometry is multi-polygon. I suppose from the strata. I would like to have coordinates of each of the 20 generated points so I can generate their respective pairs at 10 meters distance with random azimuth or st_buffer.

Does anyone know if it is possible to get the coordinates of each of the randomly generated points per stratum?

I was following the instructions from Dick Brus new book on spatial sampling. See the screenshot below.
[image]

https://dickbrus.github.io/SpatialSamplingwithR/STSI.html

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with terra like this:

Example data

```
library(terra)
v <- vect(system.file("ex/lux.shp", package="terra"))
```

Solution

```
s <- spatSample(v, 5, method="random", strata="ID_2")

plot(v); points(s, col="red")
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing you could do with polygon data is first create a random sample that is larger than you need, using `sf::st_sample`, then use the [stratified.random](https://jeffreyevans.r-universe.dev/spatialEco/doc/manual.html#stratified.random) function in the spatialEco package. All you need is a stratifying variable and the function will create a stratified subsample that is an spatial sf object.

There is also a [subsample.distance](https://jeffreyevans.r-universe.dev/spatialEco/doc/manual.html#subsample.distance) function available in the same package that subsamples based on a conditional min or max distance.

It is looking like you may be using a raster as the data that the sample is drawn from. Here is an example (if you can process your raster in memory) of a distance-based stratified sample using `subsample.distance` and `lapply` (one could also use `for`).

Add packages and create some example data, "r" is the raster that the stratification is drawn from.

```
library(sf)
library(terra)
library(spatialEco)

r <- rast(ext(485660.1887, 898660.1887, 4873781.3587, 5113781.3587), 
          resolution = 1000, crs="ESRI:54030")
  r[] <- round(runif(ncell(r), 1, 2),0)
    r <- app(focal(r, gaussian.kernel(sigma=1, s=33)), fun=round)

# available strata counts
freq(r)
```

Coerce the raster to an sf POINT object and assign "STRAT" as the column name that will define the stratifying values.

```
rsf <- st_as_sf(as.points(r))
  names(rsf)[1] <- "STRAT"
```

Now, we can iterate through the strata using `lapply` and create a distance based random sample (see help for `subsample.distance` to understand the various argument).

```
samp <- lapply(unique(rsf$STRAT), function(x) {
  subsample.distance(rsf[rsf$STRAT == x,], size = 10, d = 5000)   
}) 
  samp <- do.call("rbind", samp)
  
plot(r)
  plot(samp["STRAT"], pch=20, cex=2, add=TRUE)
```